# Travel to Puerto Rico - me and my wife have B-1/B-2 visas - do our kids needs visas as well?

Tags: visas, b1-b2-visas, children, puerto-rico, polish-citizens

We are Polish citizens, based in the UK, thinking about travel to Puerto Rico. 
Me and my wife we have B-1/B-2 Visa valid till 2021. We have two kids (4.5 and 2) who have passports but don't have visas.

**Do we need to apply for visas for them?**

Handy links:

- https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/visitor.html
- http://prfaa.pr.gov/

I gathered that children under a certain age don't need to attend an interview, but do they need visas at all?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your children need visas unless they are eligible for the [Visa Waiver Program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_Waiver_Program).  For example, if they are British citizens then they can travel with [ESTA authorisation](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/) provided that your visit to Puerto Rico will not exceed 90 days.

Comment: Thanks, will book an appointment with embassy. Can you enhance your answer with some reference / link?

Comment: @MichalStefanow your link seems to be all that is needed. The children are exempted from the requirement for an interview. If they didn't need a visa at all, the page would say so, but it does not.